# Executors are failing in Spark standalone deployment

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I am running spark on my local windows machine. It works perfectly fine when i set master as a local but when I give it a cluster master uri, It throws the following exception for each and every executor it initiates.
`17/10/05 17:27:19 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20171005172719-0006/0 is now FAILED (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Library directory 'C:\Spark\bin\.\assembly\target\scala-2.10\jars' does not exist; make sure Spark is built.)`
I was trying out spark standalone environment locally. So I have started a master node and worker node and gave the master url to my driver program. I made sure my `SPARK_HOME` environment variable is set to `C:\Spark` (the location where I placed my spark).

Any help in solving this issue would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the exact spark-submit command with arguments ?

Comment: spark-submit --class SparkApp --master spark://{IP}:7077 "D:\work\Examples\SparkExample\target\SparkExample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"

Comment: Please add your code and spark-submit command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to find the fix for this problem. The issue is caused by the path variable of spark home, It did not pick `SPARK_HOME`(environment variable) when I added a path variable `%SPARK_HOME%\bin`. I then removed that environment variable and path variable, added them again and restarted my system. IT WORKED.